# Laravel relation between 5 tables

Tags: php, laravel, orm

please what is the correct way of getting data from the MN table where one product has assigned multiple combinations of Mark / Model / Year.

E.g. product with ID 1 has following in **mmis** table:

```
id   | product_id | mark_id | model_id | year_id
178         1          1           1        2
177         1          2           1        3
176         1          3           1        1
```

other tables are: **marks, models, years.**

It's completely fine getting all requested data with just:

```
$items = ProductMmi::where('product_id', $id)
 ->with(['mark', 'model', 'year'])
 ->get();
```

The problem is, that in this way I am not able to sort result based on mark.name ASC, model.name ASC, year.name ASC.

Thank you for any advice.

update:
forgot to add my second try - ordering still in troubles...

```
$items = ProductMmi::select([
    'product_mmis.*',
    'marks.*',
    'mark_models.*',
    'mark_model_years.*'
  ])
  ->join('marks', 'product_mmis.mark_id', '=', 'marks.id')
  ->join('mark_models', 'product_mmis.model_id', '=', 'mark_models.id')
  ->join('mark_model_years', 'product_mmis.year_id', '=', 'mark_model_years.id')
  ->where('product_mmis.product_id', $id)
  ->orderBy('mark', 'asc')
  ->orderBy('model', 'asc')
  ->orderBy('year', 'asc')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way

```
$items = ProductMmi::where('product_id', $id)->with(['mark'=>function($query){
            $query->orderBy('your_column_name','ASC');
        }])->with(['model', 'year'])
            ->get();
```

or one thing if you dont want to edit your query then in the model you can do also like this

```
public function mark()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Mark::class)->orderBy('mark','asc');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution was to add orderBy methods between specific joins. E.g. the following case is working completely properly:

```
    $items = ProductMmi::select([
        'product_mmis.*',
        'marks.*',
        'mark_models.*',
        'mark_model_years.*'
      ])
      ->join('marks', 'product_mmis.mark_id', '=', 'marks.id')
      ->orderBy('mark', 'asc')
      ->join('mark_models', 'product_mmis.model_id', '=', 'mark_models.id')
      ->orderBy('model', 'asc')
      ->join('mark_model_years', 'product_mmis.year_id', '=', 'mark_model_years.id')
      ->where('product_mmis.product_id', $id)
      ->orderBy('year', 'desc')
      ->get();
```

Is there a better way to have it done in a more efficient way? Thanks.